# Redux form state input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-form

form render:

```
return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="login"
          component={RenderTextField}
          label="Login"
        />     
        <Field
          name="password"
          component={RenderTextField}
          label="Password"
        />  
        </form>
)
```

validate:

```
const RenderTextField = ({
  label,
  input,
  meta: { touched, invalid, error },
  ...custom
},props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField
    label={label}
    placeholder={label}
    error={touched && invalid}
    helperText={touched && error}

    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
  );
}
const validate = values => {
  console.log(values);
  const errors = {}
  const requiredFields = [
    'login',
    'password',
  ]
  requiredFields.forEach(field => {
    if (!values[field]) {
      errors[field] = 'Required'
    }
  })
  if (
    values.email &&
    !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
  ) {
    errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
  }
  return errors
}
```

I don't know where the error is, it's only entered in my validate once and I can't type anything in my textfield I exported my form correctly, the validation I got from the redux form documentation my RenderTextField too can anybody help me?

My validation happens normally even without me clicking on the text fields it validates first and returns me:

> the errors:
>
> {login: "Required", password: "Required"}

but I can't write in the textfield.

I found out that the problem is:

```
{...input}
{...custom}
```

Comment: Where is `validate` actually being called?

Comment: here: export default reduxForm({
  form: 'MaterialUiForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate,
})(MaterialUiForm)